# 90's-2000's animated series: protagonist with robotic hand can transform a seemingly antique motorcycle into a hoverbike

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

I can remember only a few things regarding the show, as it was long ago, and probably late at night.  However, I do remember it had to be a series, because it ended on a cliffhanger, and it was animated, and it was on the T.V. I had an antenna, not cable or satellite at the time, so I'm thinking it was on Fox or ABC or CBS or PBS or something like that, sometime between the late 90's and the early 2000's.

I remember the protagonist had something of a metallic/robotic hand, which he used as something of a key to access alien devices and converse with a motorcycle he received during the episode I watched.

The motorcycle looked like an antique out of *Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade*, and would function normally, unless you "knew how to ask".  I remember in one chase scene, the protagonist could not get away until he held his hand over something that looked like a glass disk embedded in the gas can, and asked, "Please".  Then the motorcycle transformed into a hoverbike and got the protagonist out of the tight spot.

I remember the episode ended when he went to something of a below-ground alien house, ship or bunker, but I don't remember much else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be [*Invasion America*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_America) (1998).

Actually had some big name voice talent in there, too.

> However, I do remember it had to be a series, because it ended on a cliffhanger, and it was animated, and it was on the T.V. I had an antenna, not cable or satellite at the time, so I'm thinking it was on Fox or ABC or CBS or PBS or something like that, sometime between the late 90's and the early 2000's.

The show aired in 1998, on the WB. The series actually comprised 13 half-hour episodes, but were aired in 5 pairs, plus a final episode that ran an hour and a half.

> I remember the protagonist had something of a metallic/robotic hand, which he used as something of a key to access alien devices and converse with a motorcycle he received during the episode I watched.

The protagonist was a teenage boy and half-human heir to rulership of an alien species (think Star-Lord). He used a special glove to help him control his alien powers.

There is also [an entry on TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/InvasionAmerica) (abandon all hope, yadda yadda).

Comment: I haven't watched the entire youtube series there, but I've watched enough to find it very familiar.  Granted, I was only 7 in 1998, but I do recognize the art style, and the voices are familiar.  Thanks for helping me re-discover the series!