# Looking for English Animated late 90s/early 2000 mini-series similar to Xyber9

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, soft-sci-fi, miniseries

Was trying to recall an English (American or Canadian) animated mini series I'd seen around late 90s/early 2000s. Its premier was heavily advertised on the channel where it was broadcast (might've been WB, UPN, or Cartoon Network). When I searched for it online, Xyber9 came up. However, Xyber9 is 22 eps long and I believe the show I'm looking for was only 3 episodes long. I think it was meant to be like a movie split into multiple parts. I also don't think it was set in a post-apocalyptic world.

What I remember: it starred a guy in teens/early 20s in what seemed to be "present day", middle-America. He might've been considered to have special abilities. Somehow there was super advanced technology that only he could use. There might've been aliens.

I recall a scene where he tries to figure out how to activate a futuristic bike (might have been a hover bike) and he's real excited when he finally manages to get it to work. I vaguely recall a scene at a gas station.

There were many ads leading up to the mini-series's premier so I'm surprised it's been so hard to find. Would appreciate if anybody's able to track it down!

Comment: If the correct answer is posted, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Might this be *[Invasion America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_America)* as per [90's-2000's animated series: protagonist with robotic hand can transform a seemingly antique motorcycle into a hoverbike](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150912/90s-2000s-animated-series-protagonist-with-robotic-hand-can-transform-a-seemi)?

[image: Splash image for Invasion America]

> The story of Invasion America begins in the early 1980s, when humanoid aliens from the planet Tyrus begin to initiate their plans for making contact with Earth. Cale-Oosha, the ruler of Tyrus, looks into his uncle's project with Earth. However, his uncle, The Dragit, claims that their dying planet ought to invade Earth and take hold of its resources. Cale refuses, and a civil war breaks out.
>
> Cale and Rafe, his bodyguard, trainer, and trusted friend, escape to Earth, disguising themselves as humans. Cale meets Rita Carter, a human woman; he falls in love with her, and they marry. After a long time of running from the Dragit's forces on Earth, Cale returns to Tyrus to help strengthen his loyalist forces, the Ooshati, leaving Rita and their young son, David, under Rafe's protection.
>
> In the present day, when the Dragit finally finds the family, he is determined to kill them, and David Carter's teenage life is thrown into a devastating adventure of stopping the Dragit, losing and gaining friends, and finding out just who he is.

....

> Invasion America consisted of 13 half-hour episodes, and was shown as five one-hour segments and one hour-and-a-half segment for the final episode.

### Promo

Comment: This is it. Releasing it as 6 one-hour segments sounds correct. I recall the ads made a big deal that Spielberg was attached to the project. You guys/gals are magicians around here! Thank you!

Comment: This is a blast from the past. @DarkFish I also remember that it was one of the only animated TV shows I remember appearing on prime time tv, meaning around 8pm.

Comment: @CaveJohnson, cool! I dismissed this as a teen but will go back and check it out! Thank you to the community for helping me find it.